# Unable to mount Kubernetes Secret as a File in Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to mount a config file created as a secret to a specific path in a pod. However, the mount path on the pod is always generated as a directory.  Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
> kubectl get secrets config
NAME      TYPE      DATA      AGE
config    Opaque    1         29m
```

pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd-plus-secret
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu
    name: bash
    stdin: true
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "config"
        mountPath: "/mnt/configFile"
        subPath: "configFile"
  volumes:
  - name: "config"
    secret:
      secretName: "config"
```

After the pod is created, I try to read the file on the pod, and get:

```
cat: /mnt/configFile: Is a directory
```

I am using: kubernetes client version 1.9.0 and server version 1.8.6

Comment: Have you tried running the pod without the mount and checking whether or not `/mnt/configFile` exists (and if it does, whether it's a file or a directory)? If it exists as a directory then that explains why you cannot mount a file over it. If it exists as a file or if it does not exist, then to the best of my knowledge you should be able to mount a file over it and I'd think what you're doing should work.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you want is to select just the secret's `items:`, and not try to use `subPath` in that manner. It's [documented in `SecretVolumeSource`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#secretvolumesource-v1-core)

```
  volumes:
  - name: config
    secret:
      secretName: config
      items:
      - key: configFile
        path: configFile
```

Comment: I am not sure if I didn't clarify the context enough, or am I still confused about your answer. The secrete I am trying to mount as a file is an actual file that should exist on a specific path on the file system of the pod. The contents of that file contain a lot of configuration key-value pairs.

I did try the code snippet you suggested: I removed the subPath entry in volumeMounts spec of the pod, and created the volumes just like you said. However, now my pod is just stuck in a ContainerCreating loop. Also, the documentation you pointed to seems to be v1.10, I am using k8s 1.8 (server).